# Run docker sonarqube in debug mode and not in default mode

Tags: docker, sonarqube, containers, sonarqube-scan

i try to run the **sonarqube** container in debug mode however i cant find any information on how to do it.

If i try

```
docker run -d -v sonar.conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf -p 9000:9000 sonarqube:8.2-community --debug
```

i get an error:  **Command-line argument must start with -D, for example -Dsonar.jdbc.username=sonar. Got: --debug**

Answer (score 0):

Docker is particular about where arguments are placed. It specifically says this in the CLI

```sh
$ docker --help

Usage:  docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND
```

So some options are for `docker` and additional arguments are for the command you're running, so `docker run --help` will be different than `docker --help`

This means docker options like debug mode must be set **before** `run` or any other command.

```sh
docker -D -v run sonar.conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf -p 9000:9000 sonarqube:8.2-community --debug
```